# Conversion form int to long

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, externalizable

I have created a class called `Employee` and I have an `ArrayList` for storing all the contact numbers of the employee. I have defined a method called `addcontact()` to add numbers to the list. If I use an int then it says that the number is out of range, so I changed it to long, but still I get the same error.

I am using Externalizable to serialize and deserialize the `Employee` details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `1231241241212121l` :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `L` at the end of that number (eg. 1234567890123L). Otherwise, it's considered an int constant, and therefore out of range.

Answer (score 2):

Values of type `long` should have an `L` at the end: 9929929939L.

Answer (score 1):

**Int**
Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31)
Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)

**Long**
Minimum value is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.(-2^63)
Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). (2^63 -1)